# JasperReports Server Advanced Chart Formatting Secondary Y Axis Only

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a dual axis bar and line chart that I made in an ad hoc view in JasperReports Server. In the "Chart Format" box under the "Advanced" tab, I set the 'chart.alignTicks' property to have a value of 'false', so that the ticks on the y axes are not automatically aligned with each other, as shown in the picture below.

```
chart.alignTicks: false
```

[image: chart.alignTicks: false]

There's too many gridlines, so I want to disable the gridlines for the secondary axis only (the yellow axis labelled "Cumulative Sum of Event"). I know that I can set the 'yAxis.gridLineWidth' to have a value of '0' to make gridlines disappear. However, this makes the gridlines for both y axes disappear, as shown in the picture below.

```
yAxis.gridLindWidth: 0
```

[image: yAxis.gridLindWidth: 0]

I only want the gridlines for the primary y axis ("Count of Event") to be visible. How do I use advanced chart formatting to affect only the secondary y axis?